# WaitforElement timeout error?

Tags: java, selenium, junit4, selenium-ide

I am converting my coding to Junit4(webdriver) . When I run my code in Eclipse I get an error in the below code,

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
  if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
     try { 
       if (isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("button.MB_focusable"))) break;
     }
     catch (Exception e) {}
     Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this?

Comment: what sort of error? compile error? Are you just getting a timeout fail?

Comment: There should be an error in line Thread.sleep(1000) as:

Unhandled exception type InterruptedException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call the `isElementPresent` method after creation of the `DefaultSelenium` object.

While running the testcases in Eclipse and Selenium Rc we need the object on which object should be invoked.

Try and let me know if run into any further issues.